# Combine sequences of numbers with "variable bitlengths" into short unique strings

Tags: algorithms, numbers, arithmetic

It is not unlikely that what I want to do is not possible, but it doesn't hurt to ask.

Imagine a set of lists, each containing positive integers (in my case, a list always consists of four integers, but that shouldn't make any difference).

```
a = [35, 2, 123684, 647]
b = [453, 346457546457, 6, 0]
c = ...
```

Then there is an alphabet, e.g.

```
alphabet = [A, .., Z, a, .., z, 0, .., 9]
```

What I want to do is to create a function that transforms the lists into strings using the alphabet.

```
f: (list[Int], alphabet) -> string
```

The requirements for *f* are as follows:

- f should be injective in the sense that two different lists always result in two different strings and one specific list always results in the same string each time f is called.

  Notes:

  - Two lists are equal if both contain the same elements in the same order.
  - It is ok if transformations of different lists using different alphabets result in the same string. The unique-requirement only applies to the transformation of different lists using the same alphabet.
  - An inverse function is not required.
- Now the hard part: the resulting strings must be as short as possible.

---

All of the numbers are 32 bit integers. But the fact that they vary greatly in size (the possible range is from 0 to `Int.max`) should be taken into account. Just chaining the 32 bit representations together (or doing something else that uses chunks of a fixed size) is not a viable solution.

One approach could be to choose one character of the alphabet and use it as a separator. This is basically what [hashids](http://hashids.org) does. E.g. if 'A' is the separator, all resulting strings would look like this: `"...A...A...A..."`.

What I don't like about this solution:

- The effective size of the alphabet is reduced by one, since one of the characters can only be used as a separator, not for encoding numbers. This results in longer strings, especially when using small alphabets
- The separatoritself also extends the string. Encoding a list of four integers means three additional characters in the result.

I'm wondering if there is a less obvious solution to the problem, maybe a more mathematical approach? Essentially, the problem is to "merge" multiple numbers into a single (unique) number.

Comment: Base64 encoding?  That's what the author of hashids actually recommends, if you don't need all the fancy stuff in hashids.  That's about as good a lossless compression as you're going to get with human-readable characters.

Comment: As a rough idea: use a [Huffman encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) first to convert the list into a binary number which is as short as possible. Then use Base64 encoding to convert the binary to your final string.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The question is still how the input for the Base64 encoder would look like. Just passing the 4 numbers as a byte array (with 4 * 32 bits) surely results in a larger string than the one hashids would produce.

Comment: @DocBrown Could you elaborate on how the Huffman encoding can be used to combine the numbers? In order to get unique results, I guess that I have to use the same huffman tree for all lists, not one specific tree for each list. But since the digits of the numbers are evenly distributed (instead of having digits with higher and lower frequencies which is utilized by hoffman), is there really a benefit?

Comment: I don't see how.  hashids uses base63 encoding.  With delimiters, as you already pointed out.  Its string is almost certainly going to be larger, not smaller.

Comment: @ceaaj: if the numbers are really evenly distributed among 0,...2^32-1, then combining the numbers to a byte array and afterwards encoding them with Base64 would surely *not* result in a larger string than what `hashid` will produce - quite the opposite.

Comment: Thanks for your patience but I don't get it. The two arrays `[0, 0, 0, 0]` and `[int.max, int.max, int.max, int.max]`, converted to byte arrays and encoded via Base64, result in a string of length ~22. This is not a surprise since each byte array has an effective and fixed size of 4 * 32 = 128 bits, regardless of the content (in contrast, hashids produces a string of length 8 for `[0, 0, 0, 0]`). I can't just strip the leading zeroes from the numbers, because then, `[4, 5, 3, 2]` would have the same byte array representation as `[4, 2, 7, 2]` and therefore the same Base64 string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Doc Brown hit upon the real problem: it is a compression problem. As such, first streaming the numbers to a binary representation (compressed bits, a byte array) and then encoding using the letters is probably the best solution. When you stream to a binary representation, include the length of any variable sized collection as the header before the body. The length can be 7bit encoded, or use a a fixed sized integer, as appropriate. If all of your lists are the same size, you don't need a length for them.

How I would stream this myself:

- the number of lists (length as described above)
- each list (fixed size of 4 integers)
- each item in the list 7 bit encoded -- this is a variable sized encoding
- no separator is needed

After streaming to a memory stream, I would then take the resulting  bytes, and use LZ4 or your favorite compression algorithm. Then encode that using your character set.

**Note**: at the time I wrote the answer above, I thought the arrays were going to be combined before compression. It turns out each must be compressed separately. This is a more difficult topic and requires more information about the source and usage of the arrays. You can find some information here: http://encode.ru/threads/343-Compressing-small-bits-of-data

Comment: If you don't know how to do 7 bit encoding I will post a sample.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Frank. If 7 bit encoding is the same as MSB VarInt encoding, then I'm already doing that (using the first bit of a byte to indicate whether or not the following byte belongs to the same number). The thing is that I only want to encode single arrays (with a fixed size of 4, e.g. `[1, 2, 10, 0]`), not a set of these arrays. The average size of such an array _after_ the 7 bit encoding is around 7-8 bytes.

Comment: As a subsequent step, I tried to encode the result with LZ4 and ZLIB, but the compressed output seems to be larger than the input. So either I did something wrong, or ~8 bytes is just too little to be compressed efficiently.

Comment: @ceaaj Yes I believe you have the same algorithm. It is impossible to apply compression to such a small string, except some custom compression. I am not a compression expert, but you are headed in the right direction. I don't understand why your question is mentioning separators, however. There is no need for them if the arrays are fixed size.

Comment: @ceaaj If you must compress each array separately, your best bet is to take advantage of some knowledge you have about the data therein, if any. Suppose the numbers tend to be near each other in value, within a list. You can xor the second number with the first, and xor the third with the second, etc, to obtain numbers that have smaller overall values (and shorter 7 bit encodings). You then do the reverse on decompression. Another option is to recognize some pattern of repeating numbers. If you have any more information, provide it in your question and put a heads up here.

Comment: @ceaaj Also you should know that the conversion to the character set in the end is essentially killing your compression efficiency. Most languages, such as C#, use at least two bytes per character, and you have object instance overhead in the heap. Keeping the compressed version as a byte array or a set of bytes in a larger array will always be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks, helped me alot. I mentioned the separators in the question because I learned about the 7 bit encoding only three days ago. And you are of course right with killing the compression efficiency, I only use the string as a human-readable representation for users, not internally. Thanks again :-)